# PAHO: on_message not invoked although defined

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Using Python's Paho, I am trying to print out a String to the console after I received it via MQTT from a broker. I do this, since I want to work with these data later, i.e. I want to trigger a function in case a specified temperature is hit. My code is as in many examples that I have seen on the internet, but unlike in these tutorials my on_message method is not even invoked and hence nothing is printed to the console.

Since I am new to Python and to MQTT, my question is whether I missed something crucial in my code. Why is on_message not called?

Thanks for your help!

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import json

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected - OK\n")
        client.subscribe("temperature/sensor1")
    else:
        print("Failed to connect to MQTT broker, return code ", rc)
        print("\n")       

#problem: never invoked
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):    
    print("calling on_message:\n")
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
    #in future: add global variable here

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print("log: ", buf)

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):
    print("Disconnected result code "+str(rc))

#Connecting to MQTT broker

MQTT_BROKER_HOST = 'brokeraddress.org'
MQTT_BROKER_PORT = 18330
MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL = 60

client = mqtt.Client("testName")
client.tls_set()

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_log = on_log
client.on_message = on_message
#alternative I found to on_message; however it also doesn't solve the issue
#client.message_callback_add('rootTopic/topic/uplink', on_message)

client.username_pw_set(username="user",password="password")

client.connect(MQTT_BROKER_HOST, MQTT_BROKER_PORT, MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL)
client.subscribe("rootTopic/topic/uplink")

client.loop_start()

client.publish("temperature/sensor1", "test message")

time.sleep(5)

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

The console currently prints out the following:

> log:  Sending CONNECT (u1, p1, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'testName'
>
> log:  Sending SUBSCRIBE (d0, m1) [(b'rootTopic/topic/uplink', 0)]
>
> log:  Sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m2), 'b'temperature/sensor1'', ... (11 bytes)
>
> log:  Received CONNACK (0, 0)
> Connected - OK
>
> log:  Sending SUBSCRIBE (d0, m3) [(b'temperature/sensor1', 0)]
>
> Subscribed to topic temperature/sensor1
>
> log:  Received SUBACK
>
> log:  Received SUBACK
>
> log:  Sending DISCONNECT
>
> Disconnected result code 0

Comment: Changing only the broker host/port and disabling the `set_tls()` this code works just fine against a local mosquitto broker. Are you sure the remote broker is fully spec compliment or if it deliberately doesn't send messages back to the publisher?

Comment: After I disabled set_tls() I received a "[WinError 10054]" specifying that the remote host closed the connection. What could this indicate?

Comment: That the remote broker you are using needs TLS. I only disabled it because my local broker is not TLS enabled.

Comment: Then the conlcusion would be that I actually don't receive any messages?

Comment: That would be the most likely conclusion

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help! Then I try to get in contact with the remote host.